# How do I bake my final Cycles render into a texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I'm new to blender and I would like to know  if there's any way I could bake my final render, with the shadows, the bump map etc. to one single texture that includes everything that I've done.

[image: Pre render, Showing what I want to bake in to 1 single texture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to load the map you want to save the baked image to in the node tree. It doesn't need to be connected.

Load up the blank image in the image editor then select what you want to bake to it.

Note that how the light responds will be calculated though the shader.

Comment: So basically i need to make another image texture whit nothing in it and bake "combined" ? (i just started today using blender so im not getting half of the things your saying sorry .-. )

Comment: No worries. Yes you need to load the image you want the textures to be backed onto into the material. UV unwrap the mesh then save the bakes.

Comment: Also I'd suggest rendering out the maps individually then loading them back in that way. One this that is worth baring in mind is that the viewport will not look the same as in cycles as, pre 2.8, they are different render methods.

Comment: Yeah, my problem now is that the texture is super low quality is there a way to enhance that so i could make it more realistic ?

Comment: What resolution map did you project the details on to? I usually aim to use a 4096px by 4096px map unless I need to lower it for some reason.

Comment: 2190x2190 a random one basically .

Comment: try 4096 x 4096

Comment: It worked out thx :)

Comment: No worries! Feel free to try even 8K though I'd argue anything more than that is completely unnecessary :)